# Quick event app for iPhone

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, calendar

I am looking for an app (or builtin feature) that allows adding calendar events in my iPhone using text. For example, in my Google Pixel I have an app called Quick Event that when I open a simple text field appear. If I type "Lunch with Bob thursday at 3pm" the information is parsed and an event is created in my calendar. Anything similar for iOS? I have searched all over but cannot find anything similar. I will preferably be able to add this to google calendar.

Comment: There's literally dozens of calendar apps in the App Store that do the same thing.  For instance, I use [Fantanstical](https://flexibits.com/fantastical-iphone) and use that method to enter all my events.  What have you tried already and why didn't it meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

> There's literally dozens of calendar apps in the App Store that do the same thing. For instance, I use [Fantanstical](http://flexibits.com/fantastical-iphone) and use that method to enter all my events. What have you tried already and why didn't it meet your needs? 
>   —-From comment by @fsb

[image: Download on the App Store]